# Python: Search Multiple Excel Sheets for Key Term, Return Another Cell

Tags: python, excel

I have a bunch of Excel templates that are not set up consistently in cell locations and are not in tabular form, but I am looking to pull them all together into a single table. Example, the Project field is in Sheet1, A6 in one Excel workbook but Sheet2, B5 in another.

What I'm looking to do is have a python script cycle through the Excel file and find the location of a given key term. From there, return the value N cells to the right (some of the fields have merged cells so it will need to be 2 cells to the right). Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you searching for a cell with value = 'Project' or some other criteria?

Comment: Searching for 'Project' and returning the value to the right ---> Project Xyz

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the full logic, but it will get you started. It searches the workbook for a cell with 'Report' then return the value from the offset cell.

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('test.xlsx')
shiftcol = 5 # offset from 'Report' cell
shiftrow = 5

found = False
for sn in wb.sheetnames:  # all sheets in workbook
   if found: break
   ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sn)
   for cl in range(1,51):  # search 50 columns
      if found: break
      for rw in range(1,51):   # search 50 rows
          if found: break
          if ws.cell(rw,cl).value == 'Report':  # search for first cell with this value
              print('Found Report. Sheet='+sn+' Col=' + str(cl) + ' Row=' + str(rw))
              print("Value=" + str(ws.cell(rw+shiftrow, cl+shiftcol).value)) # offset to find target value
              found = True 

if not found:
   print ("Report field not found") # didn't find cell with 'Report'
```